# Make Ansible included playbooks run on same hosts as their parent

Tags: ansible

Helllo, what is the best way to make an included playbook run on the same hosts as the playbook that called him?
I've tried declaring a variable in the parent playbook with the host name and then passing it to the included playbook, but I get an error telling me that the variable is undefined.

Below is my playbook:

```
--- 
  # Main staging configuration playbook
- vars: 
    host_name: "stage_ansible"
  hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  remote_user: ubuntu
  tasks:  
    - name: test connection
      ping:
      remote_user: ubuntu

- include: NginxDefinitions.yml
  vars:
    service_name: "interaction.qmerce.com"
    env_name: "stage4"
    host_name_pass: "{{ host_name }}"
...
```

and the error I'm receiving:

```
`ERROR! 'host_name' is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define the hosts runtime and avoid hard coding them on the playbook, you can pass the hosts [as extra variables on the command line.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line)

To do so, remove `vars` definition from your first play and add the following to the `ansible-playbook` command line:

```
--extra-vars host_name=localhost
```

or when you have multiple hosts:

```
--extra-vars '{"host_name":["host1","host2","host3"]}'
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Thanks. It also solved my next problem - how to pass variables through the command line.